# Can Linux and Mac users view pages created with ASP.NET & C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, macos

Pretty much what the title says.  I'm learning ASP.NET & C# to take advantage of .NET framework since I will be developing applications for Windows workstations for the next several years, but I wonder... if I create a database web page (as an example) with ASP.NET, will a client that's running Mac OS or Linux distro be able to view that page without any issues and use its functionalists?

**EDIT:** You guys are absolutely right.  I created a text box and then checked the source code of the test page in the browser and it showed that everything was converted to HTML.  Thank you very much for quick responses! :)

Comment: Yes.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta So, those OSes will be able to understand all the scripts with no problem?  Or does the browser do all the dirty work, so that OS wouldn't have to?

Comment: The point is, they don't have to understand the scripts. Its a server-side application, everything that goes to the client is basically HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web pages and web applications are targeted to web browsers, not specific operating systems.

Web browsers like Firefox and Chrome are cross-platform between Windows, OS X, and Linux (and some others). so if you target these two major browsers (not IE), and your app runs fine in them, you're good.

Comment: How come are there so many issues with IE?  I keep on seeing "any major browser, except IE" all the time.  Or do you mean that I should target for cross-platform browsers to make sure that the application will in fact function no matter the platform it's being used on?

Comment: There is nothing of major wrong with IE, except people insist in using ancient versions of it ("the one that came with the Windows") that are incompatible with almost everything used nowadays. Assuming you use Chrome or Firefox means your browser is always up to date, as they take care that by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms. Yes. The output from ASP.NET etc. is, usually, an HTML file. "All" browsers, regardless of platform, Windows, OS-X, or *nix, can render HTML.